# Wiring up my shop at home

Tags: wiring

I am wanting to install a 100 amp breaker in my panel box outside  my house to wire a shop about 250’ away from my house. What gauge wire do I need to use?

Comment: We need to know just how much electricity you expect to used at any given moment. You actually need to look at the name plate of each tool/piece of equipment. And add the amp draw of them together.  Calculate only those item that will consume power at the same time.  From this we have a formula to use and can give give you an answer.

Comment: What stuff are you putting in your shop? How big is the building, for that matter?  What size electric service do you have to your house?

Comment: Shop will be 24x40 will put only lights and recepticals. House outside panel box has a 200 amp service. I have found out if I’m not mistaken to use a 2,2,2,3 wire. What is best copper or aluminum wire? Thanks.